# Would a comparative math education question be welcome here?

Tags: discussion

I had to look up "BODMAS" to understand the quesiton discussed in another meta thread.

I do blame some of the problems I see on the badly chosen mnemomics like BODMAS and FOIL in comparation to the corresponding mnemomics in my country.

Now, I would be quite interested in learning what the mnemomics for BODMAS are in different countries and I think that the audience here is sufficiently international to give an interesting range of answers.
(For comparison, instead of "first, inner, outer, last", we learned "each with each" in my country, which both avoids the arbitrary order and generalizes.)

I suspect that this kind of question will get in trouble both because of people who think that it is not mathematics and because of people who think that list questions are from hell.

So, is there a form of the above question that would be welcome here?

Comment: "PEMDAS" in the U.S.  (or at least in parts of...).

Comment: BODMAS is more usually called BIDMAS in schools now (I is for "Indices") but is still awful :(

Comment: I'm not sure that this question would fit into this website's paragidm. I'd also remark that there are many languages which do not use Latin-like font, and such mnemonics would be written in a whole other language and a whole other font, I'd also mention that I am unaware of this sort of mnemonics in Israel.

Comment: You don't seem to get that I am not interesting in initials, I am interested in the actual content. When I say that in my country, we learn "each with each" instead of "FOIL", I do not mean to say that we learn it in English. Also, I don't know another country at all that uses acronyms. There is *content* here.

Comment: It's not usually true to say that mathematics education is consistent within countries. So, in this sense it's difficult to understand what you are asking.

FOIL is commonly heard in the UK (I also remember "smiling monkey face") but teachers in the UK who understand the pedagogy will use an "each with each" method, which is much better for students' understanding. 'FOIL' is not part of the UK syllabus, it is only that it is sometimes used to teach binomial multiplication.

Comment: I'm American, and my version of FOIL was to "complete the rainbow" - a sort of pictographic each-with-each. It wasn't until I hit college that everyone began to 'foil things out.'